# Composed look does not get applied to the new site collection using PnP Partner Pack

Tags: pnp, pnp-provision

I create a site collection as I made some simple modifications like I applied a new composed look which is an OOTB one. I added two pages in the site pages library. I saved the site as a template using PnP Partner Pack. Then I created a new site from this template.

When I checked the new site, I found out that the composed look was not applied and the pages were not created/copied from the site pages library.

How can I fix these two issues? 
By the way, I am using SP Online.